# cursor initialization error: column value is always -1 in content providers

Tags: android

This is the error I am getting
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.example.yaamu.survey_contentprovider, PID: 17250

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yaamu.survey_contentprovider/com.example.yaamu.survey_contentprovider.Database_Activitry}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 3, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 3, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                          at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                                                                                          at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                                                          at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
                                                                                          at com.example.yaamu.survey_contentprovider.Database_Activitry.onCreate(Database_Activitry.java:33)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is the attribute set
      /**************DATABASE TABLE 
      COLUMNS*****************************************/

```
 public static final String TABLE_DATABASE = "database_table";
public static final String COLUMN_DB_QUEST_ID = "question_question_id";
public static final String COLUMN_DB_SURVEYID = " survey_id";
public static final String COLUMN_QUESTION = " question_ques";
public static final String COLUMN_TYPE_OF_ANSWER = "type_of_answer";
public static final String COLUMN_IS_VALIDATION = "is_validation";
public static final String COLUMN_ANSWER_TYPE_FILTER = "answer_type_filter";
public static final String COLUMN_IS_REQUIRED = "is_required";
public static final String COLUMN_IS_SHUFFLE = "is_shuffle";
public static final String COLUMN_LINEAR_MIN_VALUE = "linear_min_value";
public static final String COLUMN_LINEAR_MAX_VALUE = "linear_max_value";
public static final String COLUMN_LINEAR_MIN_LABEL = "linear_min_label";
public static final String COLUMN_LINEAR_MAX_LABEL = "linear_max_label";
public static final String COLUMN_RATING_VALUE = "rating_value";
/**********************************************************************************************/
```

And the table is created.

```
  private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE = " create table "
        + TABLE_DATABASE + "("
        + COLUMN_DB_QUEST_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_DB_SURVEYID + " integer not null, "
        + COLUMN_QUESTION + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_TYPE_OF_ANSWER + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_IS_VALIDATION + " boolean, "
        + COLUMN_ANSWER_TYPE_FILTER + " text, "
        + COLUMN_IS_REQUIRED + " boolean not null,"
        + COLUMN_IS_SHUFFLE + " boolean, "
        + COLUMN_LINEAR_MIN_VALUE + " integer, "
        + COLUMN_LINEAR_MAX_VALUE + " integer, "
        + COLUMN_LINEAR_MIN_LABEL + " text,"
        + COLUMN_LINEAR_MAX_LABEL + " text, "
        + COLUMN_RATING_VALUE + " integer );";
```

The values are been added. It is shown in toast message but I am not able to retrieve the values

I have used another activity to retrieve the values

```
   Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(SurveyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI3, null, null, null, SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_DB_QUEST_ID);
    if(c!=null & c.getCount()>0)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            text1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_DB_QUEST_ID)));
            text2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_DB_SURVEYID)));
            text3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
            text4.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_TYPE_OF_ANSWER)));
            text5.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_IS_VALIDATION)));
            text6.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_ANSWER_TYPE_FILTER)));
            text7.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_IS_REQUIRED)));
            text8.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_IS_SHUFFLE)));
            text9.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_LINEAR_MIN_VALUE)));
            text10.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_LINEAR_MAX_VALUE)));
            text11.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_LINEAR_MIN_LABEL)));
            text12.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_LINEAR_MAX_LABEL)));
            text13.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_RATING_VALUE)));
        }
    }
```

THANK YOU

Comment: Use   c.moveToFirst() instead of c.moveToPosition(2)

Comment: @akhilesh0707 even that doesn't work!!

Comment: which row you want to fetch..? 3rd row only..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran everything

Comment: Make sure you close the cursor too.

Comment: @Dayan its still the same even after closing the cursor

Comment: `if(c!=null & c.getCount()>0)` statement uses the bitwise `&` and doesn't short circuit, if the cursor is null it will throw an exception on `c.getCount() > 0` - so you should use the logical `&&` operator instead. I suspect the problem is with the `ContentProvider` you're using.

Comment: @MarkKeen I used the same method for other table and its working fine

Comment: @MarkKeenCursor c2=getContentResolver().query(SurveyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI2,null,null,null, SurveyContentProvider.COLUMN_QUESTION_ID);
        if(c2!=null & c2.getCount()>0)

Comment: `I used the same method for other table and its working fine` - Isn't `SurveyContentProvider.CONTENT_‌​URI2` a different uri which will call different logic in your content provider? Also I didn't say thet the cursor is null, I said your method of checking isn't null safe.

Answer (score 0):

It was just because of an space which was initialized while defining the column attributes COLUMN_DB_SURVEYID and COLUMN_QUESTION.
Thanks for your kind replies!